# for each cell in sheet1.range if cell contains value (that's a %) paste in sheet 2 in next empty cell in column c

Tags: vba, excel

Please help! I am trying to create a macro to go through a range and based on criteria (cell value), copy that cell and the cell to the left to sheet 2 in columns next empty row.

I have tried to merge a couple of different code that i found but i haven't been able to solve. I don't think it is difficult but it is difficult for me.

My code so far:

```
Sub Ado()
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Target Calculator")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Exceptions")
    Last = 61

    With sht1
        For i = 5 To Last Step 1
            If (Cells(i, "J").Text) = "26.00%" Then
               Cells(i, "J").Value = sht2.Cells(i, "c").Value
             End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I don't have any formal training in VBA, i've been trying to learn by building and learning on this website.

Many Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like the following, assuming you have cells formatted as percentage but the actual value that would be found would be `.26`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Ado()
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, unionRng As Range

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Target Calculator")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Exceptions")
    Last = 61

    With sht1
        For i = 5 To Last
            If (.Cells(i, "J").Value) = 0.26 Then
               If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                   Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, .Cells(i, "J").Offset(, -1).Resize(1, 2))
               Else
                   Set unionRng = .Cells(i, "J").Offset(, -1).Resize(1, 2)
             End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.Copy sht2.Range("C" & sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, what if i wanted a range of percentage say >=0.01 and <=0.026 then? 
Would it be something like: 
(.Cells(i, "J").Value) >= 0.01 and (.Cells(i, "J").Value) <=0.26  Then?

Comment: Sort of. Did you want1%-26% i.e.  >=.01 and <= .26 ?